# JPA / Spring / Delete Entity, type Mismatch (int/long for id)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity which uses

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

and i have a JPA Repository for this Entity. Now i want to delete one of those, but the standard method for that is `delete(int i)`, which can't work because my ID's are not Integers, but Longs. So apart from using `int` for my IDs, what to do here? Can i specify a custom delete method which uses long, like it works with `findbyXX(XX)` ?

EDIT: 
First of all: Yes i am using Data JPA!

I want to do this:

```
   jparepository.delete(id);
```

In case id is an Integer:

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.Entity. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer
```

In case id is a long:

```
no method found for delete(long)
```

So i can either change my ID to int, which i don't want to do, or find a way to get the Repository to work with long. And the question is how

Comment: assuming you are using spring data jpa, what version are you using?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok turns out it was just a stupid mistake. So my JPARepository looked like this:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
```

But `Integer` represents the type of the Entities ID-Field, which is `Long` in my case.
So i needed to change to ..`JpaRepository<Entity, Long>`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring Data JPA, the default delete method is:

```
void delete(T entity);
```

Look here:
[Spring Data JPA Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

Also, you it's better to use Long than primitive long, because then you can use more methods when validating:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Comment: I tried to do that as well, but i get the same error (I added it to my question): Type Mismatch. That is because first i would have to get the Entity by id like `repository.findOne(id);` which also works with int per default.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about spring data JPA, yes you can specify a custom method if you want to delete by something user-defined, but that isn't necessary for a delete by ID. See the spring docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#delete-ID-

You can delete by a generic ID type that corresponds to the type of your entities' ID (in your case `Long`). This should work.